# code deployments on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, continuous-deployment

There are quite a few resources on deployments of AMI's on EC2.  But are there any solutions to incremental code updates to a PHP/Java based website?

Suppose I have 10 EC2 instances all running PHP / Java based websites with docroots local to the instance.  I may want to do numerous code deployments to it through out the day.

I don't want to create a new AMI copy and scale that up to new instances each time I have a code update.

Any leads on how to best do this would be greatly appreciated.  We use subversion as our main code repository and in the past we've simply done an SVN update/co when we were on one to two servers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should check out Elastic Beanstalk. Essentially you just package up your WAR or other code file, upload it to a bucket via AWS's command line/Eclipse integration and the deployment is performed automatically.

http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/

Answer (score 3):

Elastic Beanstalk is exactly designed to do this for you. We use the Elastic Beanstalk java/tomcat flavor but it also has support for php, ruby, python environment. It has web console that allows you to deploy code (it even keeps history of it), it also has git tool to deploy code from command line.

It also has monitoring, load balancer, auto scaling all built in. Only a few web form entries to control all these.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a tool designed to manage this sort of thing for you, Puppet is well regarded in this area.

Have a look here:

https://puppetlabs.com/puppet/what-is-puppet/

(No I am not a Puppet Labs employee :))

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano is a great tool for deploying code to multiple servers at once.  Chef and Puppet are great tools for setting up those servers with databases, webservers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Go for a Capistrano . Its a good way to deploy your code on multiple servers .

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned Elastic Beanstalk is a good option if you just want a webserver and don't want to worry about the details.

Also, take a look at AWS CodeDeploy. You can have much more control over the lifecycle of your instance and you'd be looking at something very similar to what you have now (a set of EC2 instances that you setup). You can even get automatic deployments on instance launch with Auto Scaling.

Answer (score -1):

You can either use Capsitrano or TravisCI.